# Wpa PTK and GTK in detail

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, encryption, wireshark, wpa2

I have been checking Pairwise and Group Transient keys in a network for security. I understand

PTK is derived from = PMK, AP nonce (ANonce), STA nonce (SNonce), AP MAC address, and STA MAC address

This means that every client will have a different PTK since nonce will be different for each handshake.

If so, how can i see other wireless devices that is connected to network and sending unicast packet(so ptk is used, not gtk)  from wireshark ? How can my pc decrypt those packets if ptk is used to encrypt them ?

I heard that PSK might be enough to decrypt any packet since it is derived from SSID + password with a hashing algorithm.. and since every client has the same psk, that works but if so ptk is used for what ?

Note : PMK = PSK

Comment: Are you talking about "other computers' requests" sent specifically to your computer, or about requests to some unrelated 3rd device that the computer only happens to capture?

Comment: A wireless device that is connected to network and sending unicast packet(so ptk is used, not gtk)

Comment: That's not what I asked. Is the device sending unicast packets to you, or to some other peer?

Comment: to other peers in the network. how does the routing work either way ? is p2p or is the router in middle man while routing these unicast packets ? @u1686_grawity